# Adam optimizer goes haywire after 200k batches, training loss grows

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been seeing a very strange behavior when training a network, where after a couple of 100k iterations (8 to 10 hours) of learning fine, everything breaks and the training loss *grows*:

[image: Loss explodes]

The training data itself is randomized and spread across many `.tfrecord` files containing `1000` examples each, then shuffled again in the input stage and batched to `200` examples.

#### The background

I am designing a network that performs four different regression tasks at the same time, e.g. determining the likelihood of an object appearing in the image and simultanously determining its orientation. The network starts with a couple of convolutional layers, some with residual connections, and then branches into the four fully-connected segments.

Since the first regression results in a probability, I'm using cross entropy for the loss, whereas the others use classical L2 distance. However, due to their nature, the probability loss is around the order of `0..1`, while the orientation losses can be much larger, say `0..10`. I already normalized both input and output values and use clipping

```
normalized = tf.clip_by_average_norm(inferred.sin_cos, clip_norm=2.)
```

in cases where things can get really bad.

I've been (successfully) using the Adam optimizer to optimize on the tensor containing all distinct losses (rather than `reduce_sum`ing them), like so:

```
reg_loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES))
loss = tf.pack([loss_probability, sin_cos_mse, magnitude_mse, pos_mse, reg_loss])

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate,
                                   epsilon=self.params.adam_epsilon)
op_minimize = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
```

In order to display the results in TensorBoard, I then actually do

```
loss_sum = tf.reduce_sum(loss)
```

for a scalar summary.

Adam is set to learning rate `1e-4` and epsilon `1e-4` (I see the same behavior with the default value for epislon and it breaks even faster when I keep the learning rate on `1e-3`). Regularization also has no influence on this one, it does this sort-of consistently at some point.

I should also add that stopping the training and restarting from the last checkpoint - implying that the training input files are shuffled again as well - results in the same behavior. The training always seems to behave similarly at that point.

Comment: Quick sanity check: in what order are you training your data?

Comment: Randomized batches from randomized files. Will edit.

Comment: I've seen similar scenarios when your training loss is insensitive to the norm of your vectors. Then what happens is that your quantities can grow large/small without bound, and which point limits of floating point arithmetic kick in. The way to avoid it is to make sure all quantities have regularization penalties and are on similar numeric scale

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes. This is a known problem of Adam.

The equations for Adam are

```
t <- t + 1
lr_t <- learning_rate * sqrt(1 - beta2^t) / (1 - beta1^t)

m_t <- beta1 * m_{t-1} + (1 - beta1) * g
v_t <- beta2 * v_{t-1} + (1 - beta2) * g * g
variable <- variable - lr_t * m_t / (sqrt(v_t) + epsilon)
```

where `m` is an exponential moving average of the mean gradient and `v` is an exponential moving average of the squares of the gradients. The problem is that when you have been training for a long time, and are close to the optimal, then `v` can become very small. If then all of a sudden the gradients starts increasing again it will be divided by a very small number and explode.

By default `beta1=0.9` and `beta2=0.999`. So `m` changes much more quickly than `v`. So `m` can start being big again while `v` is still small and cannot catch up.

To remedy to this problem you can increase `epsilon` which is `10-8` by default. Thus stopping the problem of dividing almost by 0. 
Depending on your network, a value of `epsilon` in `0.1`, `0.01`, or `0.001` might be good.

Comment: I had removed a separate loss function I was using and didn't see this problem anymore ... now I learn that I simply made my model worse instead. D'oh!

Comment: This is great advice. I personally use pytorch and default Adam eps is 1e-8 which is too low in my opinion. 1e-4 allowed me to train without gradient explosion with high learning rate and also no need for gradient clipping too!

Comment: Can another remedy be `beta_1 = beta_2` or it is different than changing `epsilon`?

Comment: "This is a known problem of Adam." Would you be able to link a resource where other discuss this behavior?

Comment: I've seen this advice in several places but I didn't expect to find so sound explanation under a random question on SO.
I think this might be an issue with the naming. `epsilon` just looks like some boring stability constant that you should set low and never bother with it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes this could be some sort of super complicated unstable numbers/equations case, but most certainty your training rate is just simply to high as your loss quickly decreases until 25K and then oscillates a lot in the same level. Try to decrease it by factor of 0.1 and see what happens. You should be able to reach even lower loss value.

Keep exploring! :)